# Prove $ac\cos B+ab\cos C-bc\cos A-a^2 \le \frac{c^2}{8\cos^2(90^\circ-C)}$ for $\triangle ABC$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, geometric-inequalities

> Triangle $\triangle ABC$ has sides $a$, $b$, and $c$, and circumradius $R$. Prove that
> $$ac \cos B + ab \cos C - bc \cos A - a^2 \le \frac{c^2}{8\cos^2(90^\circ - C)}$$
> When does equality occur?

I came across this question in a different forum and I thought it was interesting. I made a bit of progress but not much: I changed $R^2$ to the fraction in the inequality. I think that there is probably another use of Law of Sines or Law of Cosines but I can't find one.

Edit: A lot of people have questions about if the problem is right; here is the original problem:

Triangle $\triangle ABC$ has sides $a$, $b$, and $c$, and circumradius $R$. Prove that
$b^2 + c^2 - a^2 \ge -R^2$
When does equality occur?

Comment: Do you really mean $90$, or do you mean $90^\circ$?

Comment: Caution : the inequality is false for an equilateral triangle. Probably $\ge$ is to be changed into $\le$...

Comment: Isn't $R = \frac{c}{2\sin C}$?  Are you sure that $8$ is right?  Maybe I don't have the right setup in mind.

Comment: @Théophile: I don't think anyone seriously would read that as $90$ radians without further context. :-)

Comment: The Law of Cosines is $ac \cos B=(a^2+c^2-b^2)/2.$ And $\cos^2(90^o-C)=\sin^2 C=1-\cos^2 C=1-((a^2+b^2-c^2)/2ab)^2$ by the Cosine Law.

Comment: Following my comment, thanks for having changed ≥ into ≤. It would have been **courteous and useful** to comment/acknowledge this change. Next time, please, check your formulas before posting. Besides, there is no point keeping $\cos(90−C)^2$, because it is plainly $\sin(C)^2$...

Answer (score 1):

Id est, by the law of cosines we need to prove that:
$$\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2}+\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2}-\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2}-a^2\leq\frac{c^2}{8\left(\frac{2S}{ab}\right)^2},$$
where $S=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4)}$.

Thus, we need to prove that
$$b^2+c^2-a^2+\frac{a^2b^2c^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4)}\geq0.$$
Now, let $a=y+z$, $b=x+z$ and $c=x+y$.

Thus, $x$, $y$ and $z$ are positives and we need to prove that:
$$2(x^2+xy+xz-yz)+\frac{\prod\limits_{cyc}(x+y)^2}{16xyz(x+y+z)}$$ or
$$(y^2+34yz+z^2)x^4+2(y^3+35yz+35y^2z^2+z^4)x^3+$$
$$+(y^4+38y^3z+42y^2z^2+38yz^3+z^4)x^2+$$
$$+2yz(y^3-13y^2z-13yz^2+z^3)x+y^2z^2(y+z)^2\geq0.$$
Now, let $x^4=t\cdot\frac{y^2z^2(y^2+10yz+z^2)}{12}.$

Thus, since $$y^2+34yz+z^2\geq36\sqrt[3]{\frac{y^2z^2(y^2+10yz+z^2)}{12}},$$
$$2(y^3+35y^2z+35yz^2+z^3)\geq144\sqrt{\frac{y^2z^2(y^2+10yz+z^2)}{12}},$$
$$y^4+38y^3z+42y^2z^2+38yz^3+z^4\geq120\sqrt[3]{\left(\frac{y^2z^2(y^2+10yz+z^2)}{12}\right)^2},$$
$$2yz(y^3-13y^2z-13yz^2+z^3)\geq-48\sqrt[6]{\left(\frac{y^2z^2(y^2+10yz+z^2)}{12}\right)^5}$$ and $$y^2z^2(y+z)^2\geq4\cdot\frac{y^2z^2(y^2+10yz+z^2)}{12},$$
it's enough to prove that:
$$36t^4+144t^3+120t^2-48t+4\geq0$$ or
$$(3t^2+6t-1)^2\geq0$$ and we are done!

The equality occurs for $t=\frac{2}{\sqrt3}-1$ and, for example, for $y=z=1$, which gives $x=\frac{2}{\sqrt3}-1$ and we got a triangle with measured angles $30^{\circ}$, $30^{\circ}$ and $120^{\circ}.$

Comment: how did you get that inequality?

Comment: @mathelete I think he substituted $\cos x$ with the law of cosines definition of $\cos x$. not sure why the inequality sign got flipped or if the right-most substitution is right.

Comment: @mathelete I used law of cosines. For example: $\cos\beta=\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}.$

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the second question (equality).

> Triangle $ABC$ has sides $a$, $b$, and $c$, corresponding angles
> $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$,  semiperimeter $\rho$, inradius $r$ and
> circumradius $R$.  Prove that
> \begin{align} R^2-a^2+b^2+c^2\ge0\tag{1}\label{1}. \end{align}
> When does equality occur?

By dividing \eqref{1} by $R^2$, we have

\begin{align}
1-4\sin^2\alpha+4\sin^2\beta+4\sin^2\gamma&\ge0
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

It's easy to verify that \eqref{2} becomes an equality
for $\alpha=120^\circ,\beta=\gamma=30^\circ$.
In other words,
\eqref{1} becomes an equality
for an isosceles triangle with $\alpha=120^\circ$.

Answer (score 0):

*Alternative proof*:

We need to prove that
$$b^2 + c^2 - a^2 + \frac{a^2b^2c^2}{2a^2b^2 + 2b^2c^2 + 2c^2a^2 - a^4 - b^4 - c^4} \ge 0$$
or
$$b^2 + c^2 - a^2 + \frac{a^2b^2c^2}{4b^2c^2 - (a^2 - b^2 - c^2)^2} \ge 0$$
or
$$b^2 + c^2 - a^2 + \frac{1}{\frac{4}{a^2} - \frac{(a^2 - b^2 - c^2)^2}{a^2b^2c^2}} \ge 0. \tag{1}$$

Using $b^2c^2 \le (b^2 + c^2)^2/4$, we have
$$\frac{4}{a^2} - \frac{(a^2 - b^2 - c^2)^2}{a^2b^2c^2}
\le \frac{4}{a^2} - \frac{(a^2 - b^2 - c^2)^2}{a^2(b^2 + c^2)^2/4} = \frac{4(2b^2 + 2c^2 - a^2)}{(b^2 + c^2)^2}.\tag{2}$$

From (1) and (2), it suffices to prove that
$$b^2 + c^2 - a^2 + \frac{(b^2 + c^2)^2}{4(2b^2 + 2c^2 - a^2)} \ge 0$$
or
$$\frac{(2a^2 - 3b^2 - 3c^2)^2}{4(2b^2 + 2c^2 - a^2)}\ge 0$$
which is true.

We are done.

*Equality case*: $b = c$ and $2a^2 - 3b^2 - 3c^2 = 0$, i.e. $b = c = a/\sqrt{3}$.